# Manga where the main character gets reincarnated in a world where people are “tamers” and their beasts have skills that level up

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

After being reincarnated into another body, the guy gets two skills: one is telepathy, and the other is to level up his beast’s skill.

His beast has an appearance similar to a panda and is very hardworking, unlike the rest of his race.

The only thing I remember about the main character’s appearance is that he has brown hair.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[Unconventional Taming](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/unconventional-taming)*, the manga adaptation of the [similarly named light novel](https://m.webnovel.com/book/unscientific-beast-taming_20794057105834105)?

> This is a world where beast-taming is the norm. Animals, plants, elements, spectres, robots… the nine-tailed flame fox, tree of life, thunder cloud fairy, skeleton lord, robotic fleet maiden, and even antique blades that cultivated spirits can be kept as pet beasts. The humans who form a contract with, nurture, and tame them are known as tamers. Shi Yu, a mythologist and archaeologist, found himself transmigrated to this world. In search of a missing past and a forgotten legend, he embarks on a journey of unconventional taming…